Increase swap memory in docker desktop
Using this version of docker, 
The swap memory in docker desktop is limited to 4GB.


On windows, this default value could be doubled by specifying "SwapMiB": 8192 in a settings file located at %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json


This file is read at startup, so after making changes, restart the app.

How do I increase this limit on the macOS version of docker desktop app?

For anyone who stumbles across this, the answer is here: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/19669/increase-swap-memory-in-docker-desktop/19670

Is this no longer in the settings for the app as the vendor describes? https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/mac/

On macOS, you can’t directly tweak the swap memory through a settings file like on Windows. To increase it, try opening Docker Desktop, go to Settings > Resources > Advanced, and adjust the swap slider. If it’s capped or missing, that’s just how macOS handles it, and any other changes would be pretty hacky and might not stick after updates.

I just tried that. On Mac, SwapMiB is listed in settings.json. I changed it and restarted, but it doesn't seem to be using swap. So, perhaps this doesn't work on Mac.
